# visual-studio code ssh linux rights problem

Tags: linux, apache2, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote, access-rights

I have a linux debian server and on it is apache2, mysql, php, etc. . I used to use PuTTy and WinSCP, now I use VS-Code with the "remote - shh" extension. But I have 5 user in the group "student" and the webserver run in /var/www/html and in /home/[user]/public_html
and I blocked the usergroup "student" so they cannot read/write/execte the file in /home/[user]/public_html from the other users  files. The rights are drwx---r--, and everything is working in PuTTy and WinSCP, but when I open the terminal in vs-code and try to access the files, I can access them, instead of getting blocked (yes i tried it without su and a admin user), i need a solution for it

i changed the rights for rwx for the group ("student"), that they cannot change files in other users folder
in PuTTy and WinSCP everything is working.
When I use VS-code their terminal funtion i can access the folders, but it's not supposed to happen that i can acces it

Comment: Not exactly the scenario you described, but the Visual Studio Code Remote Development repository (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release) has an issue about groups not being applied, until you restart the remote VS Code  (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/5813).

Comment: Maybe you could look that repo for similar issues, or even report your issue there too, as it is the official location for feedback about the VS Code Remote extension.